# VM cloud based OS possible?

Tags: operating-system, cloud, virtual-machine

> "A process virtual machine (also, language virtual machine) is
>   designed to run a single program, which means that it supports a
>   single process. Such virtual machines are usually closely suited to
>   one or more programming languages and built with the purpose of
>   providing program portability and flexibility (amongst other things).
>   An essential characteristic of a virtual machine is that the software
>   running inside is limited to the resources and abstractions provided
>   by the virtual machine—it cannot break out of its virtual
>   environment. quote from the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine)"

I've been studying usage of virtual machines, especially with their importance in [Cloud Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing), and I want to know if it would be possible to develop a VM based operating system that could be scaled dynamically to use the processing power of connected servers? Use it's own local hardware for fast processing, but also boost it's performance by sending processes that don't need to return immediate responses to a cloud service.

**Is this possible, or is that concept flawed?**

Basically, the OS scaling with the connected cloud servers. The processes that are ok to send to the cloud servers for a latent response would be up to the developers of each program.

At first, I could see this being effective only for corporations in need of cost-effective massive computation. But as internet speeds increase, even front-end interface animation calculations might be possible, having less local hardware, relying more heavily on cloud services.

---

If it's possible, it would allow many scientific simulations that would otherwise need super computer time to be possible from any location in the world, at no more cost than exactly what processing is done at a specific speed. And would lead eventually to consumer devices being extremely small, 'scaleably' powerful, and very cheap, allowing people to pay for processing the same way they pay for internet service today.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible, or is that concept flawed?

Both. ;)

What you are talking about seems like what used to be called "Grid Computing". (Sun even sold it in the early 90's.) The concept was that you put a magic library on all your boxes, and your app will be able to scale out with no further work by the programmer.

This is useful -- but only if your problem is "embarrassingly parallel" (i.e. lots of independent calculations that don't affect each other.).

MPI is one such popular way to do this: http://www.linux-mag.com/id/5759/

Unfortunately, most of the time people have problems that are more lumpy (grab a bunch of data from database, do some calculations, generate PDF.) In these cases, it's simpler to figure out a good strategy and manually code it up, than try to use a magic library which can be hard to debug, and even harder to work around performance problems. I know a lot of people using AWS, and none of them use a 'magic grid library' like you are talking about. They communicate between servers using simple protocols like Queues or HTTP interfaces.

That's not because your idea won't work. It's just that their needs can be satisfied by something *much* simpler to debug/run/tune.

Another neat idea in the same vein: http://www.gocircuit.org/